# Can a stationary object acquire angular momentum?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws

I'm very confused about the concept of "spin", the "inherent angular momentum" of an object. Will any object other than elementary particles acquire spin when it's completely stationary? Like a ball placed on the ground.

Comment: Elementary particles do not acquire spin. They are born with it.

Comment: It is important to consider that stationarity is a relative concept, valid only in a few inertial systems but not in every. If the system is not exposed to any forces that are not radically unsymmetric, it's angular momentum should be conserved, so if it had no "spin", this remains. If, however rotational symmetry is broken at an instance later, without moving the object, it might acquire "spin" due to the breaking of the symmetry acting in a way a force would act.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a stationary macroscopic object can have a net spin, with the most familiar example being a [ferromagnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) where the magnetic field is generated by the magnetic dipole moments (due to electron spins) are all being aligned. This means the magnet has a net spin, unless it happens to be an isotope where the electron spins are cancelled out by the nuclear spins.

This is demonstrated by the [Einstein–de Haas effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect) where a piece of iron will slightly rotate as it is magnetized to conserve total angular momentum after the molecular spins align (producing the magnetic field). The magnetization is usually generated by an external magnetic field, but a piece of iron cooled down from above its [Curie Temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) should display the same rotation. In that case the direction of rotation axis should be arbitrary in the absence of any external magnetic field since the spin alignment is then an example of spontaneous symmetry breaking.  In either case, once the rotation is stopped by grabbing on to it (which transfers angular momentum to you and ultimately the Earth), we are left with a stationary magnet with net spin but zero macroscopic ("orbital") angular momentum.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless another object imparts angular momentum to it (since angular momentum is a conserved quantity)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about electrons, there is spin angular momentum and orbital angular momentum. The spin angular momentum is not the angular momentum of spinning electrons. In fact there is no such things as "spinning electrons". Its just a name and have no relation to actual mechanical spinning. This concept of "spin angular momentum" was made so that Heisenberg's uncertainty principle wouldn't be violated(as orbital angular momentum gave a certain value of momentum, there had to be some uncertainty).

Now, if a ball is stationary and all the particles(macroscopically) are at rest with respect to a frame of reference, then in that frame, the ball will have 0 angular momentum even if you are considering the angular momentum of electrons, because they will just cancel out due to uniformity and randomness. Due to randomness, there will be no favoured direction of total angular momentum and hence it will be 0.